# Why are the width and height of some JS Image objects switched?

Tags: html, image, coffeescript, filereader

Here is my coffeescript:

```
file = $('#fileinput')[0].files[0]
reader = new FileReader()
img = new Image()
reader.readAsDataURL file
reader.onload = (_file) ->
  img.src = _file.target.result
  img.onload = ->
    console.log 'img load', @width, @height
```

I get width 3264, height 2448. However, the picture is taller than it is wide. When I open it in Preview, it tells me the size is 2448 x 3264. Photo was taken on an iPhone while the phone/camera was in portrait/vertical. Is there orientation encoded in the image that I have to account for? I don't see any such property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Properties

Comment: Maybe tell the folks here that you are using CoffeeScript?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsbin.com/zicanaroce/1) My guess is that the image *isn't* taller than it is wide. Perhaps it has embedded rotation information the browser isn't respecting that whatever else you're using is (or vice-versa).

Comment: There's probably some exif or xmp data embedded in your image file that tells your picture view program that it was taken in portrait mode. the best advice would be to rotate it (and probably size it down, who has a 3264x2448 screen?) before putting it on your webpage. [Flickr seems to have a way to parse it client side](http://code.flickr.net/2012/06/01/parsing-exif-client-side-using-javascript-2/)

Comment: Here is an example image that is reversed: https://pwme.s3.amazonaws.com/TbR6fWPNZxMMJMZGH/1422184501.jpeg  @T.J.Crowder in your jsbin, it says width is larger. When you load the img in the browser, the height is larger. I guess the browser is reading the orientation in the exif? But when I put it as the src of an `img` tag, it's still oriented correctly – how is that happening? The Flickr JS method of reading exif is complex and not OS, so I guess I'll have to use exiftool server-side.